# What is the best way to transfer files between servers constantly?

Tags: file-transfer

I need to transfer files between servers ... no specific move, but continuos moves. What is the best way ?

scp, ftp, rsync ... other ?

Of course if it's a "common" method (like ftp) I would block just to works between the IP's of the servers.

Also I need a SECURED form to transfer files ... I mean, to be totally sure that the files have moved successfully .

Has rsync a way to know the files were moved successfully ? maybe an option to check size or checksum or whatever.

Note: The servers are in different location

Comment: What do you mean "continuous"?

Comment: continuos = each hour a bunch of files ;)

Answer (score 0):

try [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/), utility that keeps copies of a file on two computer systems